# Finding a Song from Persistent ID using Swift 2 programming

Tags: ios, swift2, mpmediaitem, mpmediaquery, mpmediaitemcollection

I am a beginner with Swift programming who is trying to re-write code that I found online that ***Finds A Song from Persistent ID***. The original code is found at this website:

http://www.ios-developer.net/iphone-ipad-programmer/development/songs-and-playlists/find-song-from-persistent-id

I want to write this code in Swift 2 (I won't use Objective-C), but I lack the knowledge and experience to translate it.

The code:

```
MPMediaItem *song;
MPMediaPropertyPredicate *predicate;
MPMediaQuery *songQuery;

predicate = [MPMediaPropertyPredicate predicateWithValue: MyPersistentIdString forProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyPersistentID];
songQuery = [[MPMediaQuery alloc] init];
[songQuery addFilterPredicate: predicate];
if (songQuery.items.count > 0)
{
//song exists
song = [songQuery.items objectAtIndex:0];
CellDetailLabel = [CellDetailLabel stringByAppendingString:[song valueForProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyTitle]];
}
```

My questions:

1) Is this code re-writeable to Swift, is it still current enough without depreciations?

2) How would I go about calling this code using a function?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, we can rewrite this in Swift.  To find if something is deprecated, check the Apple Documentation for [MPMediaItem](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMediaQuery_ClassReference/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/MPMediaQuery) and [MPMediaQuery](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMediaQuery_ClassReference/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/MPMediaQuery). If the class or some of it's methods are deprecated it will be noted there.

Here's the code rewritten in Swift as a function.  It passes in the `persistentIdString` and returns an optional `MPMediaItem`

```
func findSongWithPersistentIdString(persistentIDString: String) -> MPMediaItem? {
    let predicate = MPMediaPropertyPredicate(value: persistentIDString, forProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyPersistentID)
    let songQuery = MPMediaQuery()
    songQuery.addFilterPredicate(predicate)

    var song: MPMediaItem?
    if let items = songQuery.items, items.count > 0 {
         song = items[0]
    }
    return song
}
```

Comment: This completely answered my questions. Thank you.